# python TCP server stops accepting connections

Tags: python, windows, amazon-web-services, tcp

So, I'm running a python TCP server on a windows machine on AWS and it works as intended for a while, then all of the sudden it stops accepting more connections and it wont accept any more until I click the command line window the server is running in and press enter, then it will print out all of the failed connections with various but very similar error messages:

```
[WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
waiting  31/07/2023, 14:52:52
0 active connections
EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:992)
waiting  31/07/2023, 14:52:52
0 active connections
[WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
waiting  31/07/2023, 14:52:52
0 active connections
```

and after that the server runs as expected for a while (usually in the range hours to days), until it happens again and I cannot figure out what is causing it. from what I can tell it is like the program gets suspended for some reason such that the connections cannot be accepted until enter is pressed but I don't understand why it would. Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
import random
import hashlib
import socket
import sys
import os
import json
import ssl
import time
import datetime
from threading import Thread
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)
    ssl_context.load_cert_chain(cert, key, password='blablabla')
    s = socket.socket()  # Create a socket object
    s.settimeout(600)
    s = ssl_context.wrap_socket(s, server_side=True)
    host = "0.0.0.0" # Get local machine name
    port = 12349  # Reserve a port for your service.

    print('Server started:', host, port)

    s.bind((host, port))  # Bind to the port
    s.listen()  # Now wait for client connection.
    threads = []
    while True:
        print("waiting",  datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S"))
        for t in threads:
            t.join(0)
        threads = [t for t in threads if t.is_alive()]
        print(f"{len(threads)} active connections")
        try:
            c, addr = s.accept()
            thread = Thread(target=connection, args=(c, addr))
            thread.start()
            threads.append(thread)
            print("thread started")
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
            

def connection(conn, addr):
    conn.settimeout(10)
    try:
        print("new connection started:", addr)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"{addr} connection error:" + str(e))
    conn.close()
```

Comment: it seems that piping the cmd line output to file solves the issue (`python server.py > testfile.txt`), but I'm not sure why but it might also be a fluke